# creating list then creating dataframe takes longer than adding one row each time

Tags: python, pandas

using pandas 1.2.1

From multiple resources and I on my on experience I know that creating a list of items then using lists to create dataframe at one go take less time then adding one row each time.

For 30 S&P tickers I get their marketCap, price using API call and append it into a list then after all 30 calls has been made I create a dataframe.

```
    %%timeit
    marketcaps = []
    prices = []
    
    for ticker in sp500_df["Ticker"].tolist()[:30]:
        try:
            data = pdr.get_quote_yahoo(ticker)
        except:
            continue
        marketcap = data["marketCap"].iloc[0]
        price = data["price"].iloc[0]
        marketcaps.append(marketcap)
        prices.append(price)
        
    x = pd.DataFrame({"ticker":sp500_df["Ticker"].tolist()[:30],
                       "stockprice":prices,
                       "marketCap":marketcaps})
```

Which outputs `22.2 s ± 3.1 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Then I try it with appending data into dataframe one by one

```
%%timeit
x = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)

for ticker in sp500_df["Ticker"].tolist()[:30]:
    try:
        data = pdr.get_quote_yahoo(ticker)
    except:
        continue
    marketcap = data["marketCap"].iloc[0]
    price = data["price"].iloc[0]
    x.append({"ticker":ticker, "stockprice":price, "marketCap":marketcap}, ignore_index=True)
```

which outputs `14.8 s ± 4.57 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

I've ran them multiple times and each time it gets same results. I thought creating list at one go is much faster and have read lots of benchmarks that proves it, but it doesn't seem to be the case in such case. I would like to know why.

Thanks in advance!